# Fastest approach to add a remote repository?

Tags: git, git-checkout

I need to check-out one branch at a time (may be another at different time). To make it fastest I am doing below steps.

1. `git remote add -f origin <Repository address>` (at first time only)

and on subsequent fetches for a particular branch

1. `git checkout -b branch localbranch`

Do we have anything else to make this approach faster? I am more interested in fastening the first step.

Comment: The question is a little unclear, because the original poster doesn't explain if he wants the reduce the number of commands needed to add the remote and checkout a branch, or reduce the amount of time it takes to fetch a remote over the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your use case here, because you can't "check out" a particular folder in a repository.  In fact, your `checkout` command will result in an error:

```
$ git checkout -b branch DestinationFolder
fatal: git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches.
Did you intend to checkout 'dir1' which can not be resolved as commit?
```

If you want to *clone* a remote repository and set it to a particular branch in a single step, you can use the `-b` flag to the `clone` command:

```
$ git clone -b branch git://git.example.com/myrepository
```

This will have the side effect of also setting up a remote named `origin` pointing at the remote repository.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an alias:

```bash
[alias]
    fastcheckout = !sh -c 'git remote add -f \"$1\"; git checkout -b \"$2\" \"$3\"' -
```

Usage:

```
git fastcheckout <remote> <branch-name> <start-point>
```